# Как работают пространства имен для переменных

Tags: php

Постигаю основы ООП тестируя все подряд. Столкнулся с проблемой - вот код этой самой проблемы:

```
<?php
    namespace MyNamespace {
        $myVar = 'strong';
    }
    namespace AnotherNamespace {
        echo $myVar;
    }
```

Переменная `$myVar` находится в пространстве имен `MyNamespace`, а ее вызов идет из пространства имен `AnotherNamespace`, что означает что по идее `echo` не должна видеть `$myVar` - вопрос - почему код все-таки работает и переменная выводится в консоль? версия `php-8.1.2`

P.S. ChatGPT клянется что код работать не должен, но он - РАБОТАЕТ))) КАК? ПОЧЕМУ?

Comment: «Как работают пространства имен для переменных» — никак. [Документация](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php): «only the following types of code are affected by namespaces: classes (including abstracts and traits), interfaces, functions and constants» — переменных в этом списке нет

Comment: @andreymal, выходит что для переменных существует только или глобальная или локальная области видимости, иных ограничений нет?